Add DNS 'A' alias record does not work when via API, works fine via dashboard - Route 53
I'm trying to add a new 'A' (alias) record to a domain (Route 53) using the API (via Ruby), point to a static web site on s3 bucket (everything fine and configured correctly here) the request works without any warning/error and I can see the new record there, but it does not works.
One thing I've noticed is that when added via API, the record is show like this: (does not works) 
But when added via dashboard, the record is showed like this (and works):

The record I am using on my code is:
 subdomain = "test123"
 record_set_params = {
  hosted_zone_id: "Z00962461JGQKRJ60M6MG",
  change_batch: {
    changes: [
      {
        action: 'UPSERT',
        resource_record_set: {
          alias_target: {
            evaluate_target_health: false,
            dns_name: "test123.elfederle.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
            hosted_zone_id: 'Z3BJ6K6RIION7M',
          },
          name: "#{test1234}.elfederle.com",
          type: 'A',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Maybe it should be dns_name: "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"?

For reference, an "A" record is an address record.  A CNAME record is an alias.

nice! glad you found the solution.
